# Reading multiple files with FileReader using .map()

Tags: javascript, immutability, filereader, map-function

I have array of files and I need to format the file to json (object at this point) with bunch of other info. Here's what I have tried

```
const uploadData = Files.map((file) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    fr.onload = (event) =>{
    const fileData = event.target.result;
    return {
      query:{
         documentName: file.name,
         personId: personId,
         serviceId: serviceID,
         documentFile: fileData,
      }
     }
    }
  })
```

I want to use immutable techniques. I do have a guess why this doesn't work but have no idea how to fix it. I Think .map does not wait for filereader to read and thus returns only array of undefined values. I tried to use IIFE but was unsuccessfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
const uploadData = [],

 Files.forEach((file) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    fr.onload = (event) =>{
    const fileData = event.target.result;

      uploadData.push(query:{
         documentName: file.name,
         personId: personId,
         serviceId: serviceID,
         documentFile: fileData,
      })
    }
  })
```

Since return is occuring in the callback , you should use local var and push the data

Comment: push etc are breaking the immutability rule and I don't even think you can push to const.